# Need to Refresh Child component on Toggle Button Angular5 and Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have this scenario where I am doing translations using toggle button on different modules. The Problem is the code for toggle is written in app.component.ts and I however tried to get the language value in child components but the functionality is only working on page refresh and not on standalone.

Meaning, when i come to  home page and switch toggle from En to Fr, it doesnot work but when i goto another link in navigation, the translation works. In short, i need to refresh my child component UI whenever user changes the toggle in parent component.

Comment: I think the same scenario is requested into this question,  please feel free to check if this fit in your requirements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256891/reload-child-component-when-variables-on-parent-component-changes-angular2#40285397

Comment: I have this scenario where child component is not loaded/refreshed again when a change happens in parent component. Means I am on a child component view and do an event on a the page header(which is part of parent component), here no constructor of child component is getting invoked .How can we use changeDetection strategy for such a child component.

Comment: How you notify your child component events or subscribe?

Comment: I am subscribing using subject and observables like mentioned in :http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject. I am able to listen to the event from app but I need to invoke a service call from the listening component and re-populate my dropdowns once theres is an event from app(like hitting a togglebar). Right now the communication is happening but I don't know how to subscribe to service calls and refresh the dropdown  in listening component on the click of event.

Comment: Both these components have their own modules. But app component is the primary one since its loading the other components in application using router-link.

Comment: http://www.iamnotanengineer.com/2017/angular-4-what-is-a-subject-and-how-it-can-be-used-basic-example/comment-page-1/#comment-802 solved my problem