# In Angular 6 I am not able to load that component again if the route is same

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I am not able to load component again if route is same but the data is changed in parent component.
i have route.ts  on which all routes are written suppose /module/{name} for one component I am changing only data in parent component but route is same how deal with this situation

In parent component I am navigating to routes after getting success of api call parent component

```
this.Service.updateInfo(res['Info']);   
this.router.navigate([routeUrl] ,{relativeTo: this.route });
```

and in child rendering using router-outlet and getting data form service using

```
this.selected = this.Service.InfoData;
```

service file

```
 public updateInfo(data) {
    if(data) {
      this.InfoData = data;
    }
  }
```

but child is not getting Updated data from service once the route is same.

Comment: Both component must have one service injected. and data property must be inside service. then change data property of service from parent component, and child component gets new data via rxjs subject by subscribing to data of services. This way you dont need to reload router component

Comment: @GaurangDhorda can you help me with an example so its make clear picture to me.

Comment: first share your code. Then it will more helpful.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I have Updated my Question can you help with that or you need other data also than please comment will add it

Comment: Create behaviourSubject like this `InfoData = new BehaviourSubject<any>([]);` inside your service

Comment: subscribe InfoData from child component, and when need to change data just use `this.InfoData.next(data)` and it will gives data.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda this I have tried but issue was that for the same component its not loading even Ngoninit  2nd time so were should i call this subscribe method in child component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232112/discussion-between-shubham-singh-and-gaurangdhorda).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reload child component when variables on parent component changes. Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256891/reload-child-component-when-variables-on-parent-component-changes-angular2)

Comment: thanks @GaurangDhorda I resolved that issue through your support using BehaviourSubject.

Comment: @ShubhamSingh Can you please accept answer, I have posted the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BehaviorSubject to emit data and to revieve data from one component to new component using angular services. In your case you need like this..

```
InfoData = new BehaviourSubject<any>([]); 
  // inside your service
```

subscribe InfoData from child component, and when need to change data just use

```
this.InfoData.next(data)  //and it will gives data.
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following settings with your route configurations

1. In your root route set `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'`

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { 
  // ...
  onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload', 
  // ...
});
```

2. Disable the route reuse strategy for your component.

```
export class YourComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) { 
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
  }
}
```

**Note** This may impact performance little.

Comment: this I have tried but that doesn't work for me and giving  "onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload', " will impact my whole application

Comment: Did you tried putting to parent component `shouldReuseRoute` as you must put this to parent component defined in route.

Comment: No @Pankaj Prakash  after adding this "shouldReuseRoute" in parent component this is not allowing me to change the URL always redirecting me to by default selected Route.

Comment: Hey there. This is a sub-optimal solution. The problem is the data injected into the component is not hooked so that data changing does not update the component. Reloading the page to workaround that is only really just hiding the problem and will fail again in the future.