# How do we refresh or reload a child component in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have transaction.component.html which renders the app-deal-partners component , evertime the delete function is called I wanted to refresh and reload the child component which is app-deal-partners component.

I want to reload     `<app-deal-partners [transaction]="transaction" [forApprovalResponse]="forApprovalResponse"></app-deal-partners>`

How do we address this in angular ? Thanks.

#transaction component ts code

```
 delete(rowData: any) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.Service.delete(rowData.id)
      .pipe(finalize(() => { this.isLoading = false;}))
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
        },
        error: (err) => {
          this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
          this.isLoading = false;
        },
        complete: () => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        },
      });
  }
```

#transaction.component.html code renders app-deal-partners code

```
  <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
    <app-deal-partners [transaction]="transaction" [forApprovalResponse]="forApprovalResponse"></app-deal-partners>
  </div>
```

#app-deal-partners code html

```
 <app-table-multi-sort (dataServiceEvent)="dataServiceEvent($event)" [tableOptions]="tableOptions" [tableData]="data" (tableActionsEvent)="tableActions($event);" (editRowEvent)="editDeal($event)"></app-table-multi-sort>
```

Comment: Why do you do both `.pipe(finalize(() => { this.isLoading = false;}))` and `complete: () => { this.isLoading = false; },`? You can remove the `complete` block, because the `finalize` block already does that.

Comment: Also you can remove the `this.isLoading = false;` from the `error` block, because `finalize` already covers that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with observables:

```
private userDeleted: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
public userDeleted$ = this.userDeleted.asObservable();
delete(rowData: any) {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.Service.delete(rowData.id)
    .pipe( tap(_ => this.userDeleted.next(rowData)), finalize(() => { this.isLoading = false;}))
    .subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
      },
      error: (err) => {
        this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
        this.isLoading = false;
      },
      complete: () => {
        this.isLoading = false;
      },
    });
}
```

Template:

```
<app-deal-partners [userDeleted$]="userDeleted$" [transaction]="transaction" [forApprovalResponse]="forApprovalResponse"></app-deal-partners>
```

and the child component logic:

```
@Input()
public userDeleted$: Observable<any>;

OnInit(){
  this.userDeleted$.subscribe(_ => {
    // Logic goes there
  })
}
```

Comment: I'd add that you can also store and pass a list from the parent component without an observer and listen on change events in the child component. Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256891/reload-child-component-when-variables-on-parent-component-changes-angular2   -- isn't this a duplicate actually?

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
<app-deal-partners 
  *ngIf="!isLoading"
  [transaction]="transaction"
  [forApprovalResponse]="forApprovalResponse"
></app-deal-partners>
```

When `isLoading` is true the component is destroyed, when it is false the component is reloaded.